# Replace all 1's at a given index - numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a binary matrix of size `10-by-10`. I wanted to change all the `1's` in the matrix at a given index to `-1`

I was able to get something like this

```
import numpy as np
mat = np.random.randint(2, size=(10, 10))
index = [6,7,8,9]

mat[(mat[index,:] == 1).nonzero()] = -1
print(mat)
```

when I print this, I get something like this

```
[[-1  0 -1  1  0 -1 -1  1 -1  0]
 [ 1  0  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1  1]
 [ 0 -1  1  0 -1 -1 -1  1 -1  0]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1]
 [ 1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1]
 [ 1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0]
 [ 1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0]
 [ 0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  0]
 [ 0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  0]
 [ 1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0]]
```

But this seems to be wrong as the index is at the end of the matrix, what I wanted was

```
[[ 1  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0]
 [ 1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1]
 [ 0  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  0]
 [ 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1]
 [ 1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1]
 [ 1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0]
 [-1  0 -1  0  0 -1 -1  0 -1  0]
 [ 0  0  0 -1 -1  0 -1 -1 -1  0]
 [ 0 -1  0  0 -1 -1 -1  0 -1  0]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1  0 -1  0 -1  0]]
```

I know that `nonzero()` is not need as I am already comparing the contents to `1`, but That's the best I got.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to get the right answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `numpy.where` to select conditionally elements based on `mat`:

```
import numpy as np
mat = np.random.randint(2, size=(10, 10))
index = [6,7,8,9]

mat[index,:] = np.where(mat[index,:],-1,mat[index,:])
print(mat)
```

This will overwrite the given rows of `mat` depending on the truthiness of the original values. Where the original values in those rows were `1`, they will be overwritten with `-1`, otherwise they will be left alone.

Although note that if you have a binary matrix with only zeroes and ones, you can just flip the sign of every element in the given rows, since `0` is invariant to this transformation:

```
mat[index,:] = -mat[index,:]
```

Comment: You are right `mat[index,:] = -mat[index,:]` that din't struck me. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @akshay I'm glad I could help:)